# How can I get Belkin Wireless adapter N450 DB/N600 DB to work on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit?

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

I am new on this... This is what I get when execute `lsusb` command:

> `zheko@zheko-FX6800-01e:~$ lsusb`
>
> `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 050d:110a Belkin Components`
>
> ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: @Charo Hi Charo! You've been doing a lot of edits recently, but they have only been editing the tags, Please try not to do that, as it clogs up the review queue. I have been rejecting a lot with this reason: `Please don't do only simple tag edits. It is too minor, bungs up the review queue and can be seen as rep farming. Try to include body edits as well`. It's really nice that you want to help, but there are other posts that could do with your editing skills more than the installation ones. It is better if 2000+ rep people do minor edits, as they don't go in the review queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [rtl8192 kernel version driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du/archive/kernel-version.zip) then move it to your desktop and extract here.

Open the terminal CTRL+ALT+T then copy and paste one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8192du-kernel-version
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

when there is an upgraqde to the kernel you will need to recompile the driver.

```
cd ~/Desktop/rtl8192du-kernel-version
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8192du
```

Driver courtesy of chili555.

Comment: I get some warnings and the following error messages while executing the make command:

/home/zheko/rtl8192du/os_dep/ioctl_cfg80211.c:3567:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  size_t len = params->len;
                     ^
/home/zheko/rtl8192du/os_dep/ioctl_cfg80211.c:3568:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  struct ieee80211_channel *chan = params->chan;
                                         ^
/home/zheko/rtl8192du/os_dep/ioctl_cfg80211.c:3569:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  const u8 *buf = params->buf;
                        ^

Comment: post the error messages in your answer in code tags or to pastebin.com and put the link here.

Comment: here is the link in pastebin.com : http://pastebin.com/0ddisbjr

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: This driver does compile, I had to change the directions. Do `cd rtl8192du` then `make clean` then follow the directions in the answer.

Comment: Sweet, it is working now. Thanks a Bunch Wild Man!